# Jquery Script Not Working to accept input numbers only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, validation

I have written my Jquery script to input number only for textbox.
Following is my html code :

```
<input type="text" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" maxlength="10" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Mobile Number" required="required">
```

When I try to input some value it accepts both numbers and characters also.

My Jquery Script is :

```
$("#mobile_number").keydown(function(event) {

if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 ) {

}
else {

    if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }   
 } });
```

Comment: use regular expression to test number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have included any `version` of `jquery`, also write your code in [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) like,

```
$(function () {
    $("#mobile_number").keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9) {

        } else {
            if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z2PMs/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("mobile_number").keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        //display error message
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/HkEuf/1/

I have updated the code here check this out it works as expected .

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could try an existing solution,

like this one: http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/demos.html

or this one: http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Answer (score 0):

the range of keyCode for numbers is [95,105]; and [48,57]

```
$("#mobile_number").keydown(function(event) {
if ( (event.keyCode > 95 && event.keyCode <106)||(event.keyCode > 47 && event.keyCode <58)) {
}
else {

    event.preventDefault(); 
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this OneLiner

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return /[0-9]/i.test(event.key)">
```

Or

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return /[0-9]/i.test(event.key)">
```